# Create a list with dates which are in between start and end dates

Tags: sql, date, while-loop, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

Using SQL Server 2016. I have a table with different start and end dates

```
Start            | End
-----------------+-----------------
2018-01-01 00:00 | 2018-01-01 23:59  
2018-01-12 05:33 | 2018-01-13 13:31  
2018-01-24 22:00 | 2018-01-27 01:44
```

I now want to create a list (stored in a table variable), that contains the dates (in minute steps from start to end) for each record. There can be multiple records in the original table.

Result:

```
2018-01-01 00:00 (1st row StartDate)   
2018-01-01 00:01  
2018-01-01 00:02  
2018-01-01 00:03  
... until  
2018-01-01 23:59 (1st row EndDate)  
followed by  
2018-01-12 05:33 (2nd row StartDate)   
2018-01-12 05:34  
2018-01-12 05:35  
2018-01-12 05:36  
... until  
2018-01-13 13:31 (2nd row EndDate)  
and so on.
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANSI standard SQL and many databases, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select datestart as dte, datestart, dateend
      from t
      union all
      select dte + interval '1 minute', datestart, dateend
      from cte
      where dte < dateend
     )
select dte
from cte
order by datestart, dateend, dte;
```

Note that this is ANSI syntax.  The `recursive` keyword may not be allowed by some databases.  Date arithmetic varies by database.  Some databases may limit the number of rows being generates, so defaults need to be overridden.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, this would be:

```
with cte as (
      select datestart as dte, datestart, dateend
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(minut, 1, dte), datestart, dateend
      from cte
      where dte < dateend
     )
select dte
from cte
order by datestart, dateend, dte
option (maxrecursion 0);
```