# Create table with multiple timetable sequences when start and end dates are given (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm studying SQL and just started to use it for business. The client has a database with Oracle system.

As a response a query, I have a table as follows,

```
/* Defined as START_END_DATE_TABLE*/

Members      | Start      | End
-------------+------------+-----------
John         | 2020-01-07 | 2021-06-10   
Smith        | 2021-01-12 | 2021-02-24   
Brown        | 2021-01-24 | 2022-05-01
```

(Let's suppose types of elements in 'Start' and 'End' columns are already converted to DATE)

Using the table above, I want to get new table with query methods (Oracle SQL) as follows,

```
Members      | DATETIME
-------------+------------
John         | 2020-01-07 
John         | 2020-01-08 
...          | ... 
John         | 2021-06-09 
John         | 2021-06-10 
Smith        | 2021-01-12
Smith        | 2021-01-13
...          | ...
Smith        | 2021-02-23
Smith        | 2021-02-24  
Brown        | 2021-01-24
Brown        | 2021-01-25
...          | ...
Brown        | 2022-04-30
Brown        | 2022-05-01
```

How can I get the table above using Oracle SQL?

I saw a similar question related to SQL Server, but I could not understand completely.
[Create a list with dates which are in between start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193726/create-a-list-with-dates-which-are-in-between-start-and-end-dates)

I totally appreciate if you tell me simple guides to solve my problem.

Comment: I wish Oracle had `generate_series()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055481/create-oracle-table-rows-from-date-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join to a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT members,
       day
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT Start_DT + LEVEL - 1 AS day
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY Start_DT + LEVEL - 1 <= End_DT
       );
```

You could also use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (members, day, end_dt) AS (
  SELECT * FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT members, day + 1, end_dt
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  day + 1 <= end_dt
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY members SET order_rn
SELECT members, day
FROM   rsqfc
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Members, Start_DT, End_DT) AS
SELECT 'John',  DATE '2020-01-07', DATE '2021-06-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Smith', DATE '2021-01-12', DATE '2021-02-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brown', DATE '2021-01-24', DATE '2022-05-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | MEMBERS | DAY |
> | --- | --- |
> | John | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 |
> | John | 2020-01-08 00:00:00 |
> | John | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 |
> | ... | ... |
> | John | 2021-06-08 00:00:00 |
> | John | 2021-06-09 00:00:00 |
> | John | 2021-06-10 00:00:00 |
> | Smith | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |
> | Smith | 2021-01-13 00:00:00 |
> | Smith | 2021-01-14 00:00:00 |
> | ... | ... |
> | Smith | 2021-02-22 00:00:00 |
> | Smith | 2021-02-23 00:00:00 |
> | Smith | 2021-02-24 00:00:00 |
> | Brown | 2021-01-24 00:00:00 |
> | Brown | 2021-01-25 00:00:00 |
> | Brown | 2021-01-26 00:00:00 |
> | ... | ... |
> | Brown | 2022-04-29 00:00:00 |
> | Brown | 2022-04-30 00:00:00 |
> | Brown | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=270fde2e9dc7fc950276799dec6b9965)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function that will RETURN a list of dates for the range

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
)
  RETURN nt_date PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
  v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
BEGIN
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (v_start);
    EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
    v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1'DAY;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END generate_dates_pipelined;
/

SELECT
        c.COLUMN_VALUE 
  FROM   
TABLE(generate_dates_pipelined(DATE '2022-06-01',
DATE '2022-06-30')) c
```

If you want to call the function and associate it with a name you can do something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Member, Start_DT, End_DT) AS
SELECT 'John',  DATE '2022-04-03', DATE '2022-04-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sam', DATE '2022-06-12', DATE '2022-06-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane', DATE '2022-05-24', DATE '2022-06-01' FROM DUAL;
/

SELECT    t.member, 
                  s.column_value 
FROM      table_name t
CROSS APPLY (
               SELECT  column_value
        FROM    TABLE (generate_dates_pipelined (t.start_dt, t.end_dt))
         ) s
ORDER BY  t.member, s.column_value
```